# How to update the listview in OnResume() using asynctask

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I am having trouble in updating the listview which is loaded through Async TAsk using ArrayAdapter on OnResume().

I am send the list to the array adapter constructor.

From Activity 2, an item is added to the database and returned to activity 1. On this the added item should be updated in the listview.

Below is the code.

```
public class ActivityListView extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView listView;
    MemoDBHandler dbHandler;
    List<MemoInfo> memoList = null;
    ListAdapter adapter = null;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListFetchAsyncTask asyncList = null;
    private static final String TAG = "Msg";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

        // Get ListView object from xml
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        dbHandler = new MemoDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
        cursor = dbHandler.getFullListCursor();


        asyncList = new ListFetchAsyncTask();
        asyncList.execute();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()

                {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        viewMemo(position);
                    }
                }

        );
    }

    public void viewMemo(int position) {
        MemoInfo selectedMemo = memoList.get(position);
        Intent memoIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MemoTextDetailActivity.class);
        memoIntent.putExtra("memoID", selectedMemo.get_id());
        startActivity(memoIntent);
        //finish();
    }


    public void deleteSingleMemo(int position) {
        MemoInfo selectedMemo = memoList.get(position);
        memoList.remove(position);

        dbHandler.deleteMemo(selectedMemo.get_id());
        //This will refresh the list after deletion
        ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();


    }

    class ListFetchAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<MemoInfo>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            listView.setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(false);
            listView.removeAllViewsInLayout();

        }

        protected List<MemoInfo> doInBackground(String... params) {
            Cursor cursor = dbHandler.getFullListCursor();
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (memoList != null) {
                    if (!memoList.isEmpty()) {
                        memoList.clear();
                    }
                } else
                    memoList = new ArrayList<MemoInfo>();

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {

                        // Get version from Cursor
                        String memoText = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("text"));
                        String createdDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("createdDate"));

                        Integer id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                        Log.i(TAG, "ID = " + id);
                        MemoInfo memo = new MemoInfo();
                        memo.set_id(id);
                        memo.set_memotext(memoText);
                        memo.set_createdDate(createdDate);
                        memoList.add(memo);

                        // move to next row
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }

            return memoList;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<MemoInfo> list) {
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {

                adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_list_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.action_create) {
            Intent memoIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(memoIntent);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
            if (!memoList.isEmpty()) {

                ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: in 
`if (!memoList.isEmpty()) {
     ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
}`

you are not requiring the cursor, u need to get data from DB then update the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want update you should try this

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    new ListFetchAsyncTask.execute();// asyncList.execute();
            if (!memoList.isEmpty()) {

                ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    }
```

Comment: it's wrong way of updating the list, `AsyncTask` is a background process, if you try to update the list immediately after calling `AsyncTask` it'll never update the content in list

this operation need to done in `onPostExecuteMethod` of `AsyncTask`
`if (!memoList.isEmpty()) {
                ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }`

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
  protected void onResume()
  {
    super.onResume();
       new ListFetchAsyncTask.execute();
        if (!memoList.isEmpty()) {
         ///Use following steps 

           ///1.Here u can call the web service on the onResume method
           ////2. On post exceute of yours web service calling, you can update your listview


        }
   }
```

Comment: it's wrong way of updating the list, `AsyncTask` is a background process, if you try to update the list immediately after calling `AsyncTask` it'll never update the content in list

this operation need to done in `onPostExecuteMethod` of `AsyncTask`
`if (!memoList.isEmpty()) {
                ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }`

Comment: Ya you are right...List always update after calling the web service or you can say on the postExcecute, i Have updated my code.. @NitinMisra